# Нужно ли обособлять обстоятельство с предлогом "при"

Tags: пунктуация

Уважаемые знатоки! Уже который раз натыкаюсь на предложения, где часть с "при" выделяется запятыми:

*При общении с человеком по-английски, правильная грамматика всплывает сама собой.*

Нужно ли в таких случаях выделение запятыми?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При общении с человеком по-английски правильная грамматика всплывает сама собой.

В этом случае нет причин для обособления обстоятельственного оборота. Тем не менее обстоятельства и обстоятельственные обороты могут обособляться при наличии особых условий **(добавочное значение, удобная для обособления позиция и др.).**

Например: Правильная грамматика, **при непосредственном общении с человеком по-английски**,   всплывает сама собой.
Допустим, автору надо подчеркнуть значимость оборота, в этом случае нужно изменить его позицию и по возможности распространить его.

**Примеры с обособлением**

Хозяин, из почтения и радости, ничего не ел. Видно, и Чичиковы, на несколько минут в жизни, обращаются в поэтов . Кровля, от тяжести давившей её когда-то соломы, приняла совершенно другое направление . И тут же, от избытка чувств, предложил ему свою помощь.   Коля Иволгин, по отъезде князя, сначала продолжал свою прежнюю жизнь.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае запятая точно не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

Постановка запятой в данном случае факультативна.